# How to get currentIndex of QListView in QStyledItemDelegate::paint()

Tags: c++, qt

I defined pure virtual method `QStyledItemDelegate::paint` as:

```
void FooViewDelegate::paint( QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
    bool selected = option.state & QStyle::State_Selected;
    // ...
    // drawing code
}
```

But I cant't figure how to know is the drawing item current or no (The same item as from `QListView::currentIndex()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Qt MVC](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) is not designed for such usecases, because, theoretically, delegate should not know, what view you are using (it may be `QListView` or `QTableView`).

So, a "good way" is to keep this information inside your delegate (because model may be used by sevaral views). Fox example (pseudo-code):

```
class FooViewDelegate : ...
{
private:
  QModelIndex _currentIndex;

  void connectToView( QAbstractItemView *view )
  {
    connect( view, &QAbstractItemView::currentChanged, this, &FooViewDelegate ::onCurrentChanged );
  }

  void onCurrentChanged( const QModelIndex& current, const QModelIndex& prev )
  {
    _currentIndex = current;
  }

public:
    void paint( QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index ) const
    {
        bool selected = index == _currentIndex;
        // ...
        // drawing code
    }

}
```

Comment: Understand this idea. BTW, how does it work by default on QListView? Are they using the same trick?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know. But `QListWidget` encapsulate it's own model inside. You may look through Qt code to find exact answer.

Comment: You should remove the old idea from the answer, then. SO keeps track of your edits, the whole "EDIT: ..." "convention" is really silly. If anyone is interested in your edit history, they've got the revision tracking system to peruse.

Comment: Note that `protected: QAbstractItemView::currentChanged` is not accessible from `FooViewDelegate`. Anyway it is not problem, there are many different methods to pass the changes to `FooViewDelegate`. Thank you!

Comment: @VladimirGamalian you are right. Possible, you should do it through a selection model.

Answer (score 1):

The parent of the delegate is the view, you can directly obtain the current index from the view.

```
void FooViewDelegate::paint( QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
    bool selected = index == parent()->currentIndex();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're along the right track:

```
auto current = option.state & QStyle::State_HasFocus;
```

The item with focus is the current item.

Comment: I'v tried this, but it works until we change focus on another widget.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Try `QStyle::State_Active`. If that doesn't work, and we still assume that `option.state` has the needed data, dump it in hexadecimal and see what bit indicates the current item: `qDebug() << QString::number((uint)option.state, 16);`

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately there are only "1", "1", "1", "1", "1" after focus moved to another widget.